# Interfacing LabVIEW with python for triggering USB Camera

Tags: python, camera, labview, vision

LabVIEW supports pallete for calling function from python. Do I need to develop 3 seperate functions each for initializing, capturing and closing? Using OpenCV in python for accessing directshow based usb cameras.

If I create 3 seperate functions, do I need to include them in a same python script? As if I am using while loop for capturing function, functions written after that wont possibly be called. If I keep them in different python scripts, will it recognize that the camera is operating in a same session?

Why does subsequent functions does not recognize 'cam'?

```
import cv2
import math
import os
camname = -1
img_name = "sample"
filepath = r"C:\Users\Public"
message = "sampler"
caminitok = False
inierror = False

def caminit(camname):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camname)
    if not (cam.isOpened()):
        return inierror == True
    else:
        return inierror == False    

def camcapture(img_name, filepath, caminitok):
    if caminitok == True:
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        os.chdir(filepath)
        cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)

def camclose():
        cam.release()
```

Comment: sweber's answer is good, and will likely solve your problem. But did you know that Wineman Technology has a free, source-released bi-directional LabVIEW/Python connector? You can script LabVIEW from Python, or call Python functions from LabVIEW. The built-in Python nodes will not allow you to have Python control LabVIEW.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using global variables, a more 'Pythonic' way of maintaining a reference to an external resource would be to create a class:

```
import cv2
import os

class Cam:
    def __init__(self, camname):
        self.cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camname)
        self.caminitok = self.cam.isOpened()
    
    def capture(self, img_name, filepath):
        if self.caminitok:
            ret, frame = self.cam.read()
            os.chdir(filepath)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)

    def __del__(self):
        self.cam.release()
```

Usage:

```
>>> c = Cam(0)
>>> c.caminitok
True
>>> c.capture('foo.jpg', 'path/to/folder')
>>> del c
```

This is the equivalent of a functional global VI in LabVIEW, where internal state is stored in e.g. a shift register.

Comment: This is great, easier to understand in terms of labview, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is more a python than a labview problem in the first place.

The variable `cam` is created within `caminit()`, and it is deleted at the end of the function. So, `camcapture()` and `camclose()` do not know, what `cam` is.

You can add `cam` to the list of variables at the beginning. Then, it is always defined, and all functions can read it. **BUT** if a function wants to write to it, python will create a new variable with the same name, and use that for the rest of the function. At the end, it will forget the new variable, and put the original one in place. Therefore, you need to write `global cam` in `caminit()`, which explicitly tells python to write to the global variable. This is not necessary for the other functions, since they work on the variable, but don't write it.

```
    import cv2
    import math
    import os
    camname = -1
    img_name = "sample"
    filepath = r"C:\Users\Public"
    message = "sampler"
    caminitok = False
    inierror = False

    cam = None ##########   
    
    def caminit(camname):
        global cam ##########
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camname)
        if not (cam.isOpened()):
            return inierror == True
        else:
            return inierror == False    
    
    def camcapture(img_name, filepath, caminitok):
        
        if caminitok == True:
            ret, frame = cam.read()
            os.chdir(filepath)
            cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
    
    def camclose():
        
            cam.release()
```

Comment: Hi sweber, thank you so much for clarification. I created this program keeping in mind the structure of using palletes in labview (initialization, running in while loop and stop function). Turns out python works differently (thank you so much for explanation as I am able to clearly understand why) and as I need just the snap of the camera, I took references from sources here and modified to work with LabVIEW.

Comment: @Amlo4300 if you define a function in Python like `def myFun(foo, bar): return foo*bar`, that's like a subVI with two input terminals `foo` and `bar` and one output terminal. Any other variables you assign inside the function are like wires inside a subVI that don't connect to an input or output terminal: they're not accessible from outside the function or subVI.

Answer (score 0):

```
import cv2
import math
import os   
imagestate = False
def camcapture(camnum, img_name, filepath):
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(camnum, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
    ret, frame = cam.read()
    os.chdir(filepath)
    cv2.imwrite(img_name, frame)
    cam.release()
    return imagestate == True
```

I just call this script from LabVIEW whenever I need to take a snapshot, works great. I yet dont understand why imagestate is not returned 'True' even if whole script worked OK.

Comment: `imagestate` is set to `False` in the beginning, and is never set to anything else. The last line compares it to `True`, the result is always `False`, and that's what's returned.

Comment: Yes, I thought that only, but it gave syntax error on placing one '=' sign, I will check it again, thanks.

Comment: Before return set imagestate=true, return imagestate